# Postgres timestamp to date casting not working

Tags: postgresql, date, casting

I use PG12.

I have a timestamp `published_at` in a table that does not convert to date datatype when casting.

```sql
select published_at from my_table;
-- 2021-09-03 14:09:38.380 (timestamp)
```

When applying a date casting, I still have a timestamp.

```sql
select published_at::date from my_table;
-- 2021-09-03 00:00:00.000 (timestamp)
```

What I'm expecting:

```sql
select published_at::date from my_table;
-- 2021-09-03 (date)
```

When I do the same casting on now(), I have the expected result.

```sql
select now()::date;
-- 2022-02-19 (date)
```

Why?

Comment: `::date` **will** result in a proper `date` value. I suspect your SQL client to display that as a timestamp

Comment: Works for me: `select '2021-09-03 14:09:38.380'::date; 2021-09-03`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try in psql. I currently use DBeaver.

Comment: Yes, I would avoid DBeaver SO is full of questions regarding its presentation of data.